How can I take care of anti-aliasing/pixelation in QML when using a shader effect?
*Hi,
I'm using a shader effect for my speed gauge implementation, and it works perfectly on the desktop application without any anti-aliasing issues. However, when I run the same code on an embedded device (like a touchscreen), I notice pixelation/anti-aliasing at the edges (rounding corners) in certain areas.
I have even tried adding logic of anti-aliasing code to smooth the edges. But nothing has worked till now.
How can I fix this? Below is a version of my code for reference.
QML
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.7

Window {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property int rpm: 0
    property real normalizedRPMValue: (root.rpm <= 10000 ? root.rpm : 10000) / 10000

    Behavior on rpm {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 200
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            if (rpm < 10000) {
                rpm = rpm + 1000
            } else {
                rpm = 0
            }
        }
    }

    // Main background
    Image {
        source: "qrc:/bkgd.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

    }
    // Blue fill
    Image {
        id: blueFill
        source: "qrc:/sweep.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        visible: false
    }
    // Filled marks
    Image {
        id: rpmMarksFilled
        source: "qrc:/marks-filled.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        visible: false
    }
    // Unfilled marks
    Image {
        id: rpmMarksUnfilled
        source: "qrc:/marks-unfilled.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        visible: false
        width: implicitWidth
        height: implicitHeight
    }

    // Layer Effect
    // Note: Hide all the images that are being rendered by Shader
    Item {
        id: fillRough

        width: blueFill.width
        height: blueFill.height
        layer.enabled: true

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
            readonly property real degrees: Math.PI / 180 // used for deg -> rad translations
            readonly property var colorSource: blueFill
            readonly property var unfilledMarksSource: rpmMarksUnfilled
            readonly property var filledMarksSource: rpmMarksFilled

            // Properties needed / defined in Fragment shader
            // Shader - Not rotating any images, Cutting the images at startCutAngleRad
            // 219 - c - Angle of 0, -258 - m, y - startCutAngleRad, x -normalizedRPMValue
            // Formula - y = mx + c
            // m is calculated by (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) => (-39 - 219) / (1-0) = -258
            readonly property real startCutAngleRad: (219 + ((-258) * root.normalizedRPMValue)) * degrees
            readonly property real textureSizePx: blueFill.width
            readonly property real startCutRadius: 0.45
            readonly property real s: Math.sin(0)
            readonly property real c: Math.cos(0)
            readonly property bool fillVisible: root.rpm > 0
            fragmentShader: "qrc:/tachometerShader.frag.qsb"
        }
    }

    // Needle
    Image {

        source: "qrc:/sweep-line.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        // Rotate the image to pint to the correct value. y = mx + c
        // -258 - c - Angle of 0, -258 - m, y - rotation, x -normalizedRPMValue
        // Formula - y = mx + c
        // m is calculated by (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) => (0 - -258) / (1-0) = 258
        rotation: -258 + (258 * root.normalizedRPMValue)
        visible: root.rpm > 0
    }

    // Gradient overlayed on top
    Image {
        source: "qrc:/sweep-fade.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 65
        font.bold: true
        text: root.rpm
        color: "black"
    }
}

Shader effect code
`uniform lowp sampler2D colorSource;
uniform lowp sampler2D unfilledMarksSource;
uniform lowp sampler2D filledMarksSource;
varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
uniform lowp float s;
uniform lowp float c;
uniform lowp float startCutRadius;
uniform lowp float textureSizePx;
uniform lowp float startCutAngleRad;
uniform lowp float endCutAngleRad;
uniform lowp float rotRad;
uniform bool fillVisible;

lowp float atanApprox(lowp float y, lowp float x) {
    lowp float absX = abs(x);
    lowp float absY = abs(y);
    lowp float a = min(absX, absY) / max(absX, absY);
    lowp float s = pow(a, 2.0);
    lowp float r = ((-0.0464964749 * s + 0.15931422) * s - 0.327622764) * s * a + a;
    if (absY > absX)
        r = 1.57079637 - r;
    if (x < 0.0)
        r = 3.14159274 - r;
    if (y < 0.0)
        r = -r;
    return r;
}

void main() {
    // background
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(unfilledMarksSource, qt_TexCoord0);

    if (!fillVisible) {
        return;
    }

    lowp vec2 srcCoord11 = vec2(
                qt_TexCoord0.x * 2. - 1.,
                1. - qt_TexCoord0.y * 2.
                );

    // get polar coordinates of the current pixel
    lowp float curAngle = atanApprox(srcCoord11.y, srcCoord11.x);
    lowp float curRadius = sqrt(srcCoord11.x * srcCoord11.x + srcCoord11.y * srcCoord11.y) + 0.05;

    // make bottom-left quadrant compatible with all others
    if(curAngle < -2.) {
        curAngle += 6.28;
    }

    // cut out what's not needed
    if(curAngle > startCutAngleRad
            && curRadius < 1.0
            && curRadius > startCutRadius
            && fillVisible) {
        lowp mat2 rotationMatrix2x2 = mat2(c, -s,  s, c);
        lowp vec2 destCoord = srcCoord11 * rotationMatrix2x2;

        // convert to back to 0..1 system
        destCoord = vec2(
                    .5 + .5 * destCoord.x,
                    .5 - .5 * destCoord.y);

        lowp vec4 fill_color = texture2D(colorSource, destCoord);

        gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, fill_color, alpha);
        lowp vec4 marks_color = texture2D(filledMarksSource, qt_TexCoord0);

        gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, marks_color, marks_color.a * fill_color.a);
    }
}
`

I have even tried adding Antialiasing logic inside the shader code but nothing worked
Please find the reference image for the pixel breaking
enter image description here
*

It has nothing to do with QML; you just need to write better shader code.

Feels like reinventing the wheel. Why not use RadialGradient?
